# Command line tool for making icon files?

Tags: osx, conversion, icons

Is there any command line tool for making `icns` files to use for OS X apps?
I am aware of `icontool` but it doesn't do what i want. It converts `iconset` files into and `icns` file.

What i want it to do is:

Copy a 1024x1024 `tiff` file, then convert it into all the different sizes such as `512x512@2x`, `128x128` or `16x16@2x`.

I can do this manually but it can't be a pain and especially when doing it multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a script that does exactly what i want on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20703594

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I take into account that since you want to make an ICNS file, you probably have the image in PNG. Since converting a PNG image into an ICNS file is very time consuming, I recently developed my own CLI to do it automatically and quickly. You can install the package using the node package manager (npm) here is the link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-icns. You just need to give it a PNG and it will do all the rest for you. (Please follow the documentation for more details)

This is the node official website if you do not know what npm or node is: https://nodejs.org/en/